# Is it possible to check whether a browser is fast by JavaScript in a simple way?

Tags: javascript, performance, browser

I am building a one-page app.

I have some visual features that can be on or off.

A simple way is to ask the user whether they would like to see better effects.

However, is it possible for me to detect it from JavaScript rather than asking them?

For instance:

```
var iterations = 100000000;
for(var i = 0; i < iterations; i++ ){
  // do nothing
};
var time_took = console.timeEnd();
if(time_took < 150) {
  // good device
  launchEffects();
}
```

Is this way above reliable? Any good way to achieve this? Just approximate performance check is good, I don't want to import huge 3rd-party library.

Comment: What does _"reliable"_ and _"good"_ mean for you?

Comment: reliable means the "for loop" method works as expected. good means the browser has relative high level (for instance, on a modern model of computer) of performance.

Comment: Where is your threshold for _"relative high level of performance"_? The for loop method works as I expect. I don't know what you expect.

Comment: I don't have any specific number. I may have to try or do AB Test in real time. I just want to get a way to quantify this.

Comment: You can use the loop to quantify the current system performance.